# Нужно ли двоеточие в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли написано предложение:

*Всех разом забуду: тебя, тебя и тебя.*

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере двоеточие стоит правильно. Однако в подобных примерах наряду с двоеточием возможна постановка тире.

Двоеточие — тире.1

После обобщающего слова перед перечислением однородных членов предложения встречается наряду с обычным двоеточием также тире:  Там всё иное — язык, уклад жизни, круг людей (Коч.); Всё в них выражало неприязнь — их крикливость, самоуверенность, бесцеремонность (Гран.); Возможны другие вспомогательные персонажи — хозяин мебельного магазина, перемазанный известью маляр, зеленщик из соседней лавки (Евт.); Что её больше волнует — уход мужа или то, что в глазах окружающих перестала существовать «образцовая семья»? (газ.); И отовсюду — из каждого дома, двора, из каждой руины и переулка — бежало навстречу нам эхо (Пауст.).

Ср. возможность выбора между двоеточием и тире в следующих примерах: Его ничто не берёт (: — ) ни время, ни невзгоды, ни болезни; Конечно, он изменился (: — ) сгорбился, поседел, с морщинками в уголках рта; Трудно объяснить, чем он привлекал к себе (: — ) интеллигентностью? свободными манерами? искренностью? добротой?; Но почему он так властвовал над умами и сердцами (: — ) радовал и печалил, наказывал и прощал?; Мы оба художники (: — ) и ты и я. (См. также § 15, п. 5 и 9.)

См.: [Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация.  Д.Э. Розенталь.](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827556.html)

Answer (score 0):

Перечисление номинальное, но **не конкретное** — риторическое. Лучше употребить тире: «Всех разом забуду — тебя, тебя и тебя».